# xcode - how do I remove an item from an array within an array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, xcode4

I wish to remove an item from in an array that is nested in another array but try as I might I can't get the code to work.

This is what I have in my code:

```
    NSArray *array1 =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",nil];
    NSArray *array2 =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];
    NSArray *array3 =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"9",@"8",@"7",@"6",nil];

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:array1,array2,array3, nil];
```

I then use NSLog to show which item I want to remove.

```
    NSLog(@"Array item 1 position 3 = %@", [[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:3]);
```

This returns "d" which is correct.

So now I want to delete that item so am trying to use the following code:

```
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:arrayOfArrays [1], nil];
    [[subArray objectAtIndex:0] removeObjectAtIndex:3];
```

When it runs and hits the above line I get the following:

2013-05-22 14:19:01.070 Arrays Demo[6958:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e9d0b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff922953f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e96d8ec -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 252
    3   Arrays Demo                         0x0000000100001ca8 main + 1592
    4   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8e8127e1 start + 0
    5   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

What am I doing wrong?

HELP!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array1, array2, array3 are objects of `NSArray`. So you couldn't remove elements in those arrays. You should create these arrays as objects of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thanks - knew it would be something simple :)